# JS MAY (behave differently on different runtime) not catch the rejected promise in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

In the following code.

```js
const p = Promise.reject();;
setTimeout(() => {
    p.catch(() => console.log("Error caught"));
}, 0);
```

I expected `Error caught` is printed, but when I run it in Node v16.15.1, it crashes with `UnhandledPromiseRejection` error.

```
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "undefined".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

The error is not caught.

Then I tried in chrome 102.0.5005.63 but I got `Error caught` printed as expected.

Now I'm very confused about this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be at least one rejection handler attached to a Promise *at the moment that the Promise rejects* to avoid unhandled rejections. The Promise will have rejected (and the error will have been generated) by the time the timeout callback runs.

Your code produces an unhandled rejection in Chrome as well, as expected - add an `unhandledrejection` listener to see (though, of course, unlike Node, this doesn't crash the page)

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', () => {
  console.log('Unhandled rejection detected');
});
const p = Promise.reject();;
setTimeout(() => {
    p.catch(() => console.log("Error caught"));
}, 0);
```

Adding a `.catch` after the Promise has rejected will result in the `.catch` handler running - but the engine will already have seen that at the moment the Promise rejected, the rejection wasn't handled.

Best approach to this sort of thing - add a `.catch` handler synchronously when the Promise is created, not after any possible asynchronous action, otherwise the Promise might reject before the handler gets attached.